# How to highlight search results in PDFKit - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I use PDFKit for iOS 11, using search functions, i got some `PDFSelection` elements. How to highlight the text corresponding to this selection in the PDF?

I tried with this, but isn't working :

```
selection.color = UIColor.red
selection.draw(for: selection.pages.first!, active: true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add selection to the PDFView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!

pdfView.setCurrentSelection(selection, animate: true)
```

Also it looks like `selection.draw` is not necessary step.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're grabbing the highlighted text from a UISearchBar, here's a solution I came up with for Swift 5:

```
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ seachBar: UISearchBar) {
        let searchText = searchBar.text ?? ""
        let selectionList = pdfView.document?.findString(searchText, withOptions: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        
        guard let page = selectionList?.first?.pages.first else { return }
        selectionList?.forEach({ selection in
            selection.pages.forEach { page in
                let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
                    highlight.endLineStyle = .square
                    highlight.color = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
                    page.addAnnotation(highlight)
            }
            
        })    
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).